# Declaring Reactive Properties (Adding component blocks dynamically from array push)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

So, I'm attempting to create a Gutenburg style blog, I'm working on a block creation method. I should caveat - this is entirely my method, if this is the wrong method - ***great***, *let me know*, but **please** let me know the correct way! :)

Back to the question. In my project I have the following component.

`baseComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
    <component v-for="contentBlock in contentBlocks" v-bind:is="contentBlocks.blockComponent" v-bind:key="contentBlock.id" transition="fade" transition-mode="out-in"></component>
</template>

<script>
import CodeBlockComponent from './codeBlockComponent';

export default {
  name: 'BaseComponent',
  components: {
    CodeBlockComponent <!-- Corresponds to the name given in './codeBlockComponent'
  },
  data: () => ({
    contentBlocks: []
  })
  watch: {
    contentBlocks () {
      console.log(this.contentBlocks)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCodeBlock () {
      console.log('Code Block Added!')
      this.contentBlocks.push({ 'id': this.contentBlocks.length + 1, 'blockType': 'code', 'blockComponent': 'CodeBlockComponent', 'content': '' })
    },
    addQuoteBlock () {
      console.log('Quote Block Added!')
      this.contentBlocks.push({ 'id': this.contentBlocks.length + 1, 'blockType': 'quote', 'content': '' })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

N.B. Where above I have stripped the complexity from my template.

Within this same baseComponent I also have buttons which add blocks to the contentBlocks array, where my watch method is definitely finding blocks when added to this array (see below for a screenshot of the console output):

[image: Code Block Added! Log Check]

So, everything seems to be going ok - I'm now ready to add block Components. I add the first one, and I receive the following error in the console:

```
 vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Property or method "CodeBlockComponent" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

[image: Declaring Reactive Properties Error]

I took one look at the documentations where it advised to head to, which was here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties

An example of the `CodeBlockComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>HELLO WORLD FROM THE CODE BLOCK!!</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CodeBlockComponent',
  data: () => ({
  }),
  computed: {
  },
  watch: {
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

I took one look, and I'll be 100% honest - I don't quite understand what it is telling me to do...I feel like I have declared a reactive property? Any advise or pointers anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated!

*I'm assuming I can't simply `import CodeBlockComponent from './codeBlockComponent';` for this sort of dynamic rendering of components? (But, I really don't know at this point)...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you described should work just fine in case if you've imported and declared in

`components: { ... }`

all possible names which could be found in each `contentBlock.blockComponent`. Notice those components must have their `name: <String>` exactly the same as in your `contentBlock.blockComponent`. I can't see in your example this prop for item from `addQuoteBlock` by the way.

You also provided link on documentation, but it's about props, which works just fine in your example. Recheck section about dynamic components, maybe it will help: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components (notice links on fiddles)

One more thing to check: does your component in baseComponent.vue wrapped with some  ? Component must have single root element. Component with v-for probably won't go.

Comment: Hi Alendorff - the issue is tho, it's not working! :) And don't worry about that because I'm currently not adding quoteBlockComponents, as the same functionality will apply once I tie these in. Does the for loop make a difference? And without sounding ungrateful I don't feel like this is a helpful answer. It's too ambiguous...

Comment: I've added my `codeBlockComponent.vue` file...where you can see the name prop. I can't see what I've done wrong...

Comment: Well, helpful or not, I just made a suggestion about what could be wrong (imported  components / missing name). Unfortunately, I can't say for sure without running actual code and watching on what's going, with devtools, for example. v-for must not do any difference here. See for example https://jsfiddle.net/o3nycadu/14263/

Comment: That fiddle doesn't have the same component structure as my project - I've generated via the @vue-cli ... I don't think I can use `Vue.component()` in that way.

Comment: Oh, one more thing to check: does your component in `baseComponent.vue` wrapped with some <div> ? Component must have single root element. Component with v-for probably won't go. But that's not for sure :)

Comment: Project structure in fiddle should not make any difference here. It's just all about registration: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html.